# Login using facebook got permission issue?

Tags: angularjs, azure, oauth, facebook-login, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure mobile service to login an Angular/ionic app using Facebook.

```
client.login("facebook").then(function (data){
    console.log('logged in succesfully..')
    $state.go('menu.events');
}, function(error){
    console.log('login failed.');
});
```

The Facebook login page poped up and I entered email/password and it logged in successfully. Then it redirect to an Url

```
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback?code=AQBLNJX....l588-rnr2PLtoUJWWza....wq8OKv_LT6QZ3kgWa.......
```

and the page just shows one sentence,

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
>   [image]

I closed window and then the failed callback is called and printed 'login failed' in the console.

Comment: You need to add the redirect url to the app

Comment: In the settings of azure portal?

Comment: did you register the app on facebook? in the settings of facebook app

Comment: Yes, another developer had it set up

Comment: You need to set the redirect url and app domains in that, if you are testing it on localhost. add it as localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are also using Ripple.  See the following blog post on auth + mobile apps + Ripple.  https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/04/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-3-azure-ad-authentication/

The blog post covers AAD, but the Ripple + Mobile Apps information is valid for every auth provider.

Comment: Finally it works after the cors and config find editing. Thanks. Which port ionic/Cordova phone app uses? The link doesn't mention it.

Comment: It's more a Ripple thing, which I did mention in the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the redirect url and app domains on facebook app,

For sample, if you are running the app on localhost,

[image]

[image]